# Maximize crates in consumer electronics (computers)

Tags: simcity-2013

~98% of my city is educated and I have about 170k people.
I have 2 universities in order to get enough room for everyone to fit in.
I also use a library but it seems somewhat useless.

The above gives random tech levels to my consumer factories. Some are maxed out while others are yellow-coded or even have no tech level at all. In fact, only about 10% is maxed out, and about 20 % is 'yellow-teched'.

However, some factories produce 9000 crates of computers while others only produce 4000. They all have 4 computer addons as well as enough resources and workers and power and enough delivery trucks and no traffic jams and etc.
Some factories that run 9000 crates have 0 tech level.

So I don't get it anymore... How do i maximize the crates to 9000?
The same problem occurs for processor factories btw.

Comment: The official name of the game is just SimCity, the SimCity tag refers only to the 2013 edition. The tag for older games is still simcity-4

Comment: Ah okay got it.

Answer (score 2):

I contacted EA customer support regarding this question.

It seems that these are 'possible issues' according to customer support. These included:

- Random tech levels for consumer factories.
- Random crates / assembly line
- Possible delivery vehicle problems.

I was also told that the amount of crates produced may be somewhat random in order to simulate the real-life situation more closely.

So chances are, that my lower production are caused by bugs. I was assured however that a developer would get back at me regarding this.

Comment: Of course they never got back to me.